# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Error on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to post on facebook wall using access token when i use my facebook login it works but when other user use, it doesnt work.

for posting i use my account and authorize the user with login after getting access token using access token post on facebook wall.

It is not working with other user's login, please help.

**Code**

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                           'appId'  => $conf->get("FACEBOOK_API_ID"),
                           'secret' => $conf->get("FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID"))
                        );
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$params = array(
            'description'  => $campaign['message'],
            'message'      => $campaign['message'],
            'picture'      => $campaign['image_path'],
            'created_time' => strtotime($campaign['post_datetime']));
$facebook->setAccessToken($campaign['access_token']);
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$facebook->api("/$user/feed", "POST", $params);
```

By using my App ID/API Key and App Secret, i want to post on user's wall. for posting on user's wall user will have the login box where he/she will login and then i got the access token by using this access token i will post on specific time. By using cron i am posting on user's  wall by using that access token.

One thing i'm using my App ID/API Key and App Secret for getting user's access token.

I got the access token but after getting this access token i want to post and when i am hitting the cron url it gives me the error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/xyz/public_html/xyyy/plugin/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1271

Please help, how can i do the posting?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => Config::get('FACEBOOK_API_ID'),
    'secret' => Config::get('FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID'),                                'scope'=>'create_note,manage_pages,photo_upload,publish_actions,publish_stream,share_item,status_update,video_upload'
    ));
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user_id) {
    try {
        $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.Config::get('FACEBOOK_API_ID').'&client_secret='.Config::get('FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID').'&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token='.$accessToken;
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
        $response = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);

        parse_str($response, $token_data);

        $access_token = $token_data['access_token'];
```

Comment: Is your app still in sandbox mode maybe? If that’s not it, check your user’s access token with the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: Are you sure you're really logging your users in correctly? it sounds like you're trying to post using the app access token, for users who may not have granted your app publish_actions or publish_stream permissions

Comment: how can i set this publish_actions or publish_stream permissions, see updated code $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => Config::get('FACEBOOK_API_ID'),
  'secret' => Config::get('FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID'),
  'scope'=>'create_note,manage_pages,photo_upload,publish_actions,publish_stream,share_item,status_update,video_upload'
     ));
     $user_id = $facebook->getUser();